# Starting point of Android drawLine changes with angle

Tags: java, android, line, android-canvas

I'm drawing a line from a fixed point and moving it in a circle. Depending on the angle of the line (specifically which quarter of the circle the angle is within) the starting x and y co-ordinate of the line change. See this [video](https://vimeo.com/70694932) to see what I mean.

I've put a white 2x2 pixel square behind the line to better show the change in the starting x and y co-ordinates. The line should be drawn from the bottom right pixel of the square.

Here is the code which I am running in my DrawFrame method:

```
radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
x2 = 15.0 * Math.cos(radians);
y2 = 15.0 * Math.sin(radians);
c.drawLine(80, 140, 80 + (float)x2, 140 + (float)y2, mPaint);
angle += 1;
```

c is the Canvas and mPaint is a new Paint() object.

I'm new to Android, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, with floating point precision, your starting point is the exact center of the white box, which is the left and top of point 80, 140.

[image]

You might be happier with the results if you have your line start in the middle of the pixel-- like using 80.49 and 140.49 for you center.

[image]

Either way, you are just suffering from rounding problems in trying to draw a fine line with clunky pixels.

Comment: Ahh, I see! I just tested this and I think this can be fixed by adding .49 or .51 to the x and/or y depending on the angle range. Thank you very much!